# Angular- html2pdf is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas, html2pdf

I was trying to make a pdf generator for my dashboard. It was working fine in chrome, but in firefox and IE, the graphs break.
Also, I am unable to view certain images.
What could be the reason?
[This is in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni4YT.jpg)
and
[This is in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XQOj.jpg)

this is my code:

```
download(){
     const value = this.routes.url;
     const segment = /\/portal\/vc-portal\/(.+)/.exec(value)[1];
     const filename = segment.replace('/', '_').replace('-', '_');

     const element = document.getElementById('router') as HTMLElement;
     const opt = {
     pagebreak:    {mode:['avoid-all']},
     filename:     filename + '.pdf',
     image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1},
     html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
     jsPDF:        { unit: 'pc', format: 'a3', orientation: 'portrait' }
     };

    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

    }
```

How could something, work so good in one browser not work in the other?

This is the code of the circle-progress:

```
        <div class="progress-custom">
                <svg class="progress-circle" width="220px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle class="progress-circle-back"
                            cx="85" cy="85" r="80"></circle>
                    <circle class="progress-circle-prog" [ngClass]="{'progress-color-purple': showInPurple}"
                            cx="85" cy="85" r="80" [ngStyle]="{'stroke-dasharray': progress * 5.04 + ', ' + 999}"></circle>
                </svg>
                  <div class="progress-text">
                        <ng-content select="[ktCircleProgressBody]"></ng-content>
                  </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#:~:text=Maximum%20size%3A%20HTML5%20canvases%20have,rendering%20completely%20blank%20in%20html2pdf. I would recomment you to use html2canvas and jspdf latest versions together and write your own logic.

Comment: @AakashGarg Will check it out

Comment: @user18067747: you might also try to add a `viewBox="0 0 220 200"` attribute to your gauge svg

Comment: @herrstrietzel I didn't change anything